# Multiple typecasting for one variable

Tags: php, types

Is there a way to enforce variable to be one of multiple types?

Something like:

```
class MyClass
{
    public function __construct(YourClass or TheirClass $incomingObject)
    {
        if($incomingObject instanceof YourClass){
            echo 'Im your class';
        }else{
            echo 'You\'re mine class';
        }
    }

    public function helloWorld(YourClass or TheirClass or RandomClass $greetable)
    {
        echo 'something..';
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you want to force it you can have all the classes extending the same base class and put the base class name instead of your statement with or.
Anyway, it is not mandatory to precise the type of the argument in the first line of a function in PHP. You can read this: http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should define an interface for `YourClass` and then make all classes that will be passed to whatever support that interface. Then type hint to the interface instead of the class.

```
interface IYourClass{

   public function doStuff();
}

class YourClass implements IYourClass {

   public function doStuff() {
      return "This is a '".__CLASS__."'";
   }
}

class MyClass {
   public function __construct(IYourClass $object){
      $this->message = $object->doStuff();
   }

   public function helloWorld() {
      echo "Hello world! ".$this->message;
   }
}
```

Comment: Possibly the cleanest and most proper answer here. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You are unable to do it as you described. You'll have to do it like the following:

```
public function __construct($incomingObject)
{
    if($incomingObject instanceof YourClass){
        echo 'Im your class';
    }else if ($incomingObject instanceof TheirClass){
        echo 'You\'re mine class';
    }else{
        throw new InvalidArgumentException();
    }
}
```

Comment: Probably `public function __construct(object $incomingObject)`?

Comment: Ah, you added the InvalidArgumentException(), that's the only reason why I wanted this, to enforce the built in PHP error handling.

Comment: @hakre The ain no such thing as an object typehint.

Answer (score 2):

No, type hinting does not allow that. You will have to do the test at runtime yourself using the [`instanceof`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.type.php) operator.

You don't state your goal here, but usually in PHP there is no need to do this at all. If you are going to call methods on the object, and the argument is not of a "correct" class then PHP is going to give you a runtime error anyway.

The only case in which this would actually do something meaningful is if you have two completely unrelated classes with methods or properties of the same name, and you pass an instance of one (which is not indended to be used with `MyClass`) instead of an instance of the other (which is). But that would have to be a *rare* occurrence.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [get_class()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-class.php) function and do some checking behind the scenes:

```
public function helloWorld($greetable)
{
    $type = get_class($greetable);
    if ($type !== 'YourClass' || $type !== 'TheirClass' ... ) { /* Rejection */ }

    // Do other stuff
}
```

The alternative is to overload the function and have tons of copies of it.

Comment: Be careful! `get_class` is a slippery slope, because unlike `instanceof` you have to *manually* check all classes in a hierarchy. For example, if `class Giraffe extends Animal` and you pass a `Giraffe`, `get_class($animal) == 'Animal'` would fail.